# Grunt index file not running

Tags: gruntjs, watch

I am trying to get my index.html at the root of my app (app/index.html) running with grunt from I file I inherited.

My grunt file is as follows:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// 1. All configuration goes here
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    sass_directory_import: {
        your_target: {
            files: {
                src: ['css/sass/parts/_all.scss']
            },
        },
    },
    connect: {
      server: {
        options: {
          port: 9000,
          hostname: 'localhost',
          base: ['./'],
          keepalive: true,
          open: {
          target: 'http://localhost:9000'
        }
        }
      }
    },
    sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                loadPath: require('node-bourbon').includePaths,
                sourceMap: true
            },
            files: {
                'css/style.css' : 'css/sass/style.scss',
                'css/style-ie.css' : 'css/sass/style-ie.scss'
            }
        },
    },
    watch: {

        sass: {
            files: 'css/sass/**/*.scss',
            tasks: ['sass_directory_import','sass']
        }
    }
});

// 3. Where we tell Grunt we plan to use this plug-in.
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass-directory-import');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');

// 4. Where we tell Grunt what to do when we type "grunt" into the terminal.
grunt.registerTask('default',['watch', 'connect:server']);
grunt.registerTask('build',['sass', 'uglify']);
```

};

I want index to appear under the port: http://localhost:9000 but when I run the default watch task, only get the sass files being watched for changes and nothing else. How do I get grunt to run the file under the given port? I have only used Gulp before and am not finding grunt very easy to work with. Is there a grunt server/connect task that does not have to be installed?

Comment: Not familiar with `grunt-index`, but does the plugin serve the file similar to `grunt-contrib-connect`?

Comment: Not familiar with grunt-connect but I presume that yours is more along the lines of what I need. Does I run your chosen file under a given port?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-connect yes, the plugin is well documented on how you can configure it

Comment: Hey that worked, thanks (see above edits). My only problem now is that the watch task seems to take forever and do nothing when I register connect as part of my grunt default tasks. I simply get `Running "watch" task Waiting...` in terminal and `http://localhost:9000/` cannot be reached. Is there something I am not doing right?

Comment: IMO `grunt-contrib-serve` works best as a stand alone process, separate from a watch task, the process has to stay active to serve the file.  I usually have two terminal windows up for each instance